# Computing sums on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to sum 2^i from i=0 to i=n on VBA. Where n is an entered value by the user each time

I can get it to do each term individually but its not summing.

```
Sub Button1()
Dim n As Single

n = InputBox("Enter a value for n")

Dim array as

Dim CSeriesSum As Double

ActiveCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.SeriesSum(Arg1:=2, Arg2:=n, Arg3:=1, Arg4:=1:n)

End Sub
```

I expect it to return for eg. 1 if n=0, 3 if n=1, 7 if n=2 etc.

Comment: Why not just return `2^(n+1) - 1`?

Comment: In that case if you entered n=2 then it would return 2^2 = 4.

I want it to return 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2

Comment: I said return `2^(n+1) - 1`, not just `2^(n+1)`. This is a standard formula, which corresponds to the fact that a binary number which is all 1's is 1 less than a power of 2. For example, `1111` in base 2 is 16-1 = 15 in base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe try this loop:**

```
Sub Button1()

Dim n As Single

n = InputBox("Enter a value for n")

Dim val As Long

    val = 0
    For i = 0 To n

        val = val + 2 ^ i

    Next

ActiveCell.Value = val

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the loop-based approach, you can use the fact that the series

```
1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^n + ...
```

is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) whose partial sums can be expressed in closed-form. In this case the partial sum that you are evaluating is equal to `2^(n+1)-1`. For example, if `n = 3`, it is easy to verify that

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15 = 16-1 = 2^4 - 1
```

This leads to the following code:

```
Sub Button1()
    Dim n As Long
    n = InputBox("Enter a value for n")
    ActiveCell.Value = 2 ^ (n + 1) - 1
End Sub
```